# Get formalArgs from a list of functions R

Tags: r

Lets say I am passing a list of functions using the `...`

```r
distributions <- function(...){
  dist_list <- list(...)
}
```

Now if I run `distributions(rnorm(50), TidyDensity::tidy_normal())` then I get back a list with a vector and a data.frame.

My question is how can I get the name of the function called ie `rnorm()` and the parameters passed to it?

Using something like `dist_list %>% map(formalArgs)` gives `NULL` and `In formals(fun) : argument is not a function`

Comment: Once the values of `...` are evaluated, you can't get back to the original passed values. You'd need to intercept the unevaluated symbols using something like `substitute` before passing to list. Though that does make things a lot more complicated. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? There may be better, more R-like ways to do what you want. `formalArgs` works for functions, not for function calls.

Comment: @MrFlick isn't the OP just looking for `match.call`?

Comment: @AllanCameron it looked like the op was trying to get the info from “dist_list” after it was a evaluated but if you capture the unevaluated expressions with match.call instead that’s also a good work around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for `match.call` ?

```r
distributions <- function(...){
  as.list(match.call())[-1]
}

distributions(rnorm(50), TidyDensity::tidy_normal())
#> [[1]]
#> rnorm(50)
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> TidyDensity::tidy_normal()
```

Or perhaps, if you want access to both the evaluated and unevaluated expressions:

```r
distributions <- function(...){
  setNames(list(...), sapply(as.list(match.call())[-1], deparse))
}

distributions(rnorm(50), TidyDensity::tidy_normal())
#> $`rnorm(50)`
#>  [1] -0.52410930 -0.48754350 -0.31346114  1.11142888 -0.16829168  0.14389782
#>  [7]  1.87285979  0.22663043 -1.18221292 -0.65343574 -0.36147761 -1.03521579
#> [13]  1.33469895  0.21420578  1.22697541 -0.39742602  0.57371164  1.36802888
#> [19] -0.46048771 -1.40676587  0.38244090 -0.74532223 -0.10575884  0.88656441
#> [25]  1.03761952  0.11923645 -1.25080762  0.04605158  1.13500076 -0.45793246
#> [31] -0.74270252 -0.35263243  1.51000758  0.02781866  1.80205985 -1.13545504
#> [37]  1.21807981 -0.52062922 -0.54958956  0.54630736  0.22934998 -1.57051922
#> [43]  0.52189051 -0.01885723 -1.59054477  0.57197369 -1.44277344 -0.64757076
#> [49] -1.76299781  0.64173935
#> 
#> $`TidyDensity::tidy_normal()`
#> # A tibble: 50 x 7
#>    sim_number     x      y    dx       dy     p        q
#>    <fct>      <int>  <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1 1              1 -0.895 -3.63 0.000224 0.5   -Inf    
#>  2 1              2  0.648 -3.49 0.000616 0.508   -2.05 
#>  3 1              3  0.153 -3.34 0.00149  0.516   -1.74 
#>  4 1              4  1.36  -3.20 0.00318  0.524   -1.54 
#>  5 1              5  0.632 -3.05 0.00597  0.533   -1.39 
#>  6 1              6  0.830 -2.91 0.00990  0.541   -1.27 
#>  7 1              7 -0.428 -2.77 0.0146   0.549   -1.16 
#>  8 1              8  0.435 -2.62 0.0193   0.557   -1.07 
#>  9 1              9  1.25  -2.48 0.0233   0.565   -0.981
#> 10 1             10 -0.701 -2.33 0.0267   0.573   -0.901
#> # ... with 40 more rows
```

<sup>Created on 2022-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>